# ER Diagrams - Can a relationship have a multi-valued attribute?

Tags: database-design, entity-relationship, data-modeling

As title; are multivalued attributes allowed on a relationship? For example, I want to create 2 entities - landlord and tenant. I want to add a multivalued attribute, 'Contract', to the 'Rents_to' relationship. The attributes under the multivalued attribute 'Contract' would contain 'Contract_start_date', 'Contract_end_date' and 'Contract_ID'.

Answer (score 1):

Is this really a question about how to draw a diagram or about how to model data? You haven't specified which ER notation you are using. Any ER diagram is just a picture of some entities and relationships and if you need to illustrate multi-valued attributes then you should be able to do so.

Most modern DBMSs, software tools and data modellers eschew multi-valued attributes because of their distinct disadvantages for many applications.